# What is an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Is an algebra or 'a algebra' the same thing as an algebraic structure?
Or does it have a different meaning?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [universal algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra)? Or [algebra over a field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field)? It would really help if you mentioned, where (or in which context) you've encountered the term.

Comment: x is a collection of number, with ring operation

Answer (score 17):

Depends a bit on the context, but "an algebra" is often taken to mean a specific kind of algebraic structure, namely, a vector space with a multiplication operation (or a ring with a vector space structure). See, for example, this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) entry.

Answer (score -3):

A couple of years behind but I think it would still be of some pedagogical value.

It is helpful to distinguish between an "Algebra" and an "Algebraic structure", not that such a distinction actually exist but only to make it as clear as possible. 
....................................................................................................................................................

Algebra is a very general concept and it is roughly defined as follows:

An *algebra* **A** is a set A together with one or more operation o(i) (i=natural numbers). 
                       **A**= {*A*, O(1), O(2), ....O(n)}

Ex: <*A*, + , *>

Ex: <{0,1}, |(Sheffer stroke) >       this is basically the semantics of first-order logic 
....................................................................................................................................................

Algebraic Structures are the familiar structures like groups, fields and rings that are usually taught in a general abstract algebra course. 
.....................................................................................................................................................

These are basically the same creatures, the difference makes sense as long as we insist on differentiating them based on their immediate significance for the modern mathematics.

Comment: I don't think so. A group is certainly an algebraic structure, but I've never heard anyone refer to a group as an algebra, even though it has an operation.